# rails not seeing my length tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

I'm using rspec, rails 3.2.1, and i'm running tests on my Devise "User" model.

For some reason all my tests having to do with length are not working (all the tests are failing), yet I have put in the necessary validations.. also, my "required" validations are working fine.

as a side question, how do i order my validation messages? the username error messages are showing at the bottom even though its the first input box

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :bio, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  username_regex = /\A[\w_]+\z/i

  validates :username, :presence   => true,
                       :uniqueness => true,
                       :format     => { :with => username_regex,
                                        :message => "Username can only contain letters, numbers and underscores." },
                       :length     => { :minimum => 3,
                                        :maximum => 15 }

  validates :bio,      :length     => { :maximum => 255 }

end
```

here is the code for my tests that are failing

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before(:each) do
    @attr = { 
      :username => "TestUser",
      :email    => "fake@hell.com",
      :password => "123456",
      :bio      => "This is my bio"
    }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given a valid attribute" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end

  it "should require a username" do
    no_username_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:username => ""))
    no_username_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require an email" do
    no_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => ""))
    no_email_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject spaces in username" do
    space_username = User.new(@attr.merge(:username => "Test User"))
    space_username.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject usernames that are too long" do
    long_username = User.new(@attr.merge(:username => "#{'a'*16}"))
    long_username.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject short bios" do
    long_bio = User.new(@attr.merge(:bio => "12"))
    long_bio.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject long bios" do
    long_bio = User.new(@attr.merge(:bio => "#{'b'*256}"))
    long_bio.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should allow no bio" do 
    no_bio = User.new(@attr.merge(:bio => ""))
    no_bio.should be_valid
  end
end
```

Comment: So which specs exactly are failing?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server?  Also, what happens when you try to create a user in the console without validations?  Does it display your length validations when you call user.errors?

Comment: I am a moron. Restarting the server fixed the issue :x thank you Phillip

Comment: I've done it myself.  Glad it worked.

Comment: just curious.. what warrants a restart? I thought you only restarted if you change routes. I was only changing the models and tests though

Comment: Also how do i reorder the validation messages?

Answer (score 0):

It may be because your server is caching, try to restart it.